# durable-rules python how to negate a statement

Tags: python, durable-rules

How do I negate a statement? https://pypi.org/project/durable-rules/

I would like something like this but the `!` doesn't work.

```
with ruleset('awv'):
    @when_all(m.visits.anyItem(item.cpt_codes.anyItem( item.matches('G0438') | item.matches('G0439') )))
    def had_awv_exam_or_awv_visit_more_than_12_month(c):
        print('had_awv_exam_or_awv_visit_more_than_12_month')
    @when_all(m.visits.anyItem(!item.cpt_codes.anyItem( item.matches('G0438') | item.matches('G0439') )))
    def never_awv_exam_or_awv_visit(c):
        print('no_awv_exam_or_awv_visit')
```

Comment: Negation in Python is usually with the word `not`, not the `!` operator.  Does that work?

Comment: no, that doesn't work.

Comment: When frameworks use the bitwise operators (`&` and `|`), negation is usually `~`, but for me that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `-` is what you are searching for... At least it looks like that to some extend in the [documentation](https://github.com/jruizgit/rules/blob/master/docs/py/reference.md#simple-filter), but I don't know enough about the framework to tell whether it really does what you want.

If it doesn't, I'd suggest to manually negate your statement:

```
@when_all(m.visits.anyItem( item.cpt_codes.allItems( (item != "G0438") & (item != "G0439") ) ))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\valerio\Documents\excelsior-atl\backend\cronjobs\awv.py", line 85, in <module>
    @when_all(m.visits.anyItem(item.cpt_codes.allItems( item != 'G0438' & item != 'G0439' )))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'value'

Comment: Some brackets were missing, edited.